# Are etale morphisms separated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Are etale morphisms separated?

They've gotta be right? But I can't find a reference, which makes me think they're not, and yet I can't find a counterexample.

Does anyone have a counterexample?

Comment: One can define étale as flat+separable+unramified.

Comment: Is the "obvious" map from the affine line with doubled origin to the affine line étale for you? I think it is for me — locally on the source it's an isomorphism.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Is that standard? Do you have an example of someone who does that? The definition I usually use is "flat + unramified" or "smooth of relative dimension 0", which seems to agree with the definitions here: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GH

Comment: @Hoot Ok good point.

Comment: étale is a local property but separated is not.

Answer (score 4):

Etale morphisms are not separated necessarily. Indeed, let $X$ be the affine line with a double origin. The morphism $X\to \mathbb A^1$ sending both origins to the same point is a classical example of a non-separated etale morphism.

Etale is defined as formally etale + locally finite presentation. You can show that this is equivalent to flat, formally unramified and locally finite presentation. Adding separable (in the sense that the morphism the residue field extensions are separable) is redundant.